# Book recommendation application: How to make a function that can go through the database and find users that have read a particular book

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

The main feature of the application is as follows

1. Allow the user to find whether any of his friend has read a particular book or not.
2. Allow the user to find if any of his friend's friend has read a particular book or not e.g. if person A has a friend B who happens to have a friend C who has read the book that person A is interested in we should be able to make a link between the two.

I am using Kotlin and Firestore.

My database structure is as follows

1. There is a user collection that contains all the details about the user and array list of the IDs of all the books that he has read.
2. There is a friends collection that contains the root user ID and all his friends user IDs.

   **data class friends(
   val userID: String = "",
   val friendsList: ArrayList = ArrayList()
   )**

The function to find the desired link between users based on the books they have read is as follows.

```
fun findLink(mBookID: String) {
        mFireStore.collection(Constants.FRIENDS)
            .whereEqualTo(Constants.USER_ID, getCurrentUserID())
            .get()
            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                for (i in document.documents) {
                    val rootUser = i.toObject(friends::class.java)!!
                    val rootUserFriendList = rootUser.friendsList
                    for (j in rootUserFriendList) {
                        mFireStore.collection(Constants.FRIENDS)
                            .whereEqualTo(Constants.USER_ID, j)
                            .get()
                            .addOnSuccessListener { document ->
                                for (k in document.documents) {
                                    val branchUser = k.toObject(friends::class.java)!!
                                    val branchUserArray = branchUser.friendsList
                                    for (l in branchUserArray) {
                                        if (userReadBook(l)) {
                                            val linkArray: ArrayList<String> = ArrayList()
                                            linkArray.add(l)
                                            linkArray.add(j)
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                    }
                }
            }
            .addOnFailureListener { e ->
                Log.e(
                    activity.javaClass.simpleName,
                    "Error while finding a link.",
                    e
                )
            }
    }
```

The idea is to make an array of list of users leading to the actual person who has read the book. As there could be several search links I need a method to store all those arrays.

Any help in either achieving the given task or a lead to resources that could help me in achieving the task would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What's the issue with the shared code?

Comment: I am having a fairly hard time in storing all of the linkArrays into a master array which then would be passed on to other activity for display and other subsequent purposes